# Another example of Talmy's Ca1 factor in attention phenomena?

Tags: cognitive-linguistics

I'm a cognitive science student and I am studying the book "Oxford Handbook of Cognitive Linguistics".
Leonard Talmy has put a great effort in attention theory, but the part about Ca1 factor has just an example from Tamil language which is really hard to understand.
Factor Ca1 is like this:

> Factor Ca1: A Form Designating an Outside Referent as the Object of Attention

if it is a global categorization of language phenomenons, there should be some other examples from other languages, help to find some please.

Comment: Not all types of linguistics use this same terminology, so I looked it up (thanks for citing your sources! It made it much easier to search). It seems like this is referring to something like a topic marker or focus marker. Topic markers play a big role in Japanese and Korean syntax, so you might want to check those out.

Comment: @matan-matika thank you very much for your help. i found some examples of topic markers in Korean, Japanese and even Persian, and it was enough for my presentation and they were accepted.